# Pass session variable to new page when link is clicked

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having a bit of trouble with this. I have a search results page of books with various links, all linking to the same page (book.php) and I want to set a session variable to pass through to the new page which should display more info about the specific result link that is selected. I am trying to pass the variable $_SESSION['booktitle'] through to book.php when the link in the while loop is selected. The code of the search results page is:

```
<form id="rform" name="formsort" action=""  method="post">
<select name="sort" id="sort" onChange="document.forms['formsort'].submit()">
<option value="default">Sort Results</option>
<option value="lowhigh">Price: Low to High</option>
<option value="highlow">Price: High to Low</option>
<option value="az">Alphabetical Order: A-Z</option>
<option value="za">Alphabetical Order: Z-A</option>
</select>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['title']))
    {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="title" value="'.$_POST['title'].'" />';
    }
if(isset($_POST['author']))
    {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="author" value="'.$_POST['author'].'" />';
    }
if(isset($_POST['isbn']))
    {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="'.$_POST['isbn'].'" />';
    }
if(isset($_POST['keyword']))
    {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="'.$_POST['keyword'].'" />';
    }
?>
</form>
<?php
include "include.php";
session_start();
// Defining variables from home.php if set
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
$isbn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['isbn']);
$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);

if(isset($_POST['sort'])){
$sort=@$_POST['sort'];}
// Determine the WHEREs to use
$where = array();
if ( ! empty($title))
$where[] = "booktitle LIKE '%" . $title . "%'";
if ( ! empty($author))
$where[] = "author LIKE '%" . $author . "%'";
if ( ! empty($isbn))
$where[] = "isbn LIKE '%" . $isbn . "%'";
if ( ! empty($keyword))
$where[] = "description LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'";

//Determine the ORDERs to use
$order = array();
if ((isset($sort)) && ($sort=='lowhigh'))
$order[] = "price ASC";
if ((isset($sort)) && ($sort=='highlow'))
$order[] = "price DESC";
if ((isset($sort)) && ($sort=='az'))
$order[] = "booktitle ASC";
if ((isset($sort)) && ($sort=='za'))
$order[] = "booktitle DESC";
// Build the query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM book';
if ( ! empty($where))
$query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
if(! empty($sort))
$query .= ' ORDER BY ' . implode($order);
//Display results
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Error in query $query: " . mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ?><a id="1" href="book.php" border="0"><img src="<?php echo $row[12]; ?>" width="112px" height="150px" /></a>
<a href="book.php?booktitle='<?php echo $_SESSION['booktitle']=$row[1];?>'"><b><?php echo  $row[1] . ", (" . $row[5] . ")";?></b></a><br><?php
echo $row[2];
echo "<br><div style='text-align:right'> <b>&pound;" . $row[9] . "</b></div>";
echo "<b>Book description:</b> " . substr($row[3],0,300) . "...<br /><hr>";
}
mysqli_close($con);             //closes the connection
?>
```

and I call it in book.php using:

```
<?php
include "include.php";
session_start();
$book=$_SESSION['booktitle'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE booktitle='$book'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Error in query $query: " . mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[1];
} ?>
```

But no matter what book link I select, the booktitle of the 1st search result in the while loop is being echoed out. Any idea why?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello @user2197354 : I will be glad if i can help you but just if you can please post enough code so i can stand up over your real problems because your code here is not enough and at least the idea or the logic of your program is not clear enough to me so please can you give me additional explaining and additional information of your problem then when you post your code try to organise it in a way that will reflect the real purposes it is used for :)

I am waiting your edit so i can help you :)

Comment: Thank-you Last Breath. I hope I have explained it a bit better now :)

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
$book=$_SESSION['booktitle'];
```

**With**

```
$book=$_GET['booktitle'];
```

You can get `booktitle` from link using `GET` method.

Instead of using `$row[1]` replace it with `$row['booktitle']`

Comment: When I replace this line I get an error message 
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\book.php on line 8
Error in query SELECT * FROM book WHERE booktitle=''The Magic Finger'':

Comment: Do I have the wrong syntax for mysqli somewhere else? Sorry, i don't have much experience with this

Comment: $row[1]; is the booktitle from the database

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but changing it to $row['booktitle']didn't make a difference, im still getting the error message :( Do I still use <a href="book.php?booktitle='<?php echo $_SESSION['booktitle']=$row[1];?>'"> in the first page or do I replace that with $_GET['booktitle'] also?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that i can offer you my maximum help .

First of all i want to understand what is the file name where the first block exists if the second block is `book.php` ?

Then i want to suggest that you use the `session_start()` in the top of your code to eliminate any "header warnings" .

Then i want from you to explain to me why you put in your code this instruction

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['booktitle']=$row[1]?>
```

why you don't write it as :

```
<?php
$_SESSION['booktitle'] = $row[1];
echo $_SESSION['booktitle'];
?>
```

Then always after echoing a `$_SESSION['variable']` **that is needed just for one time** do an `unset()` for it after echoing it directly look like this in your case `unset($_SESSION['booktitle']);`

What i think that your new booktitle search is not stored in a new session during the above code and the old search result is just stored try to apply these modifications and tell me if it is solved :)