# How do I get php to 'remember' the conducted search after selecting to sort results?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
<?php
include "include.php";
session_start();
// Defining variables from home.php if set
if(isset($_POST['title'])){
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
}
if(isset($_POST['author'])){
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
}
if(isset($_POST['isbn'])){
$isbn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['isbn']);
}
if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);
}
if(isset($_POST['sort'])){
$sort=@$_POST['sort'];}
// Determine the WHEREs to use
$where = array();
if ( ! empty($title))
$where[] = "booktitle LIKE '%" . $title . "%'";
if ( ! empty($author))
$where[] = "author LIKE '%" . $author . "%'";
if ( ! empty($isbn))
$where[] = "isbn LIKE '%" . $isbn . "%'";
if ( ! empty($keyword))
$where[] = "description LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'";

//Determine the ORDERs to use
$order = array();
if ((isset($sort)) && ($sort=='lowhigh'))
$order[] = "price ASC";
if ((isset($sort)) && ($sort=='highlow'))
$order[] = "price DESC";
// Build the query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM book';
if ( ! empty($where))
$query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
if(! empty($sort))
$query .= ' ORDER BY ' . implode($order);
//Display results
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Error in query $query: " . mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ?><a id="1" href="book.php" border="0"><img src="<?php echo $row[12]; ?>" width="112px" height="150px" /></a>
<a href="book.php?booktitle='<?php echo $_SESSION['booktitle']=$row[1];?>'"><b><?php echo  $row[1] . ", (" . $row[5] . ")";?></b></a><br><?php
echo $row[2];
echo "<br><div style='text-align:right'> <b>&pound;" . $row[9] . "</b></div>";
echo "<b>Book description:</b> " . substr($row[3],0,300) . "...<br /><hr>";
}
mysqli_close($con);             //closes the connection
?>
```

It passes inputs from four text fields on a front end page and displays the results. This all works fine. It's when I come to sorting the displayed results. If I selected Price: low to high for example, it arranges all the results in my database and displays everything, not just the results from the conducted search. Does anyone now how I can get it to remember the original search?

This is my form:

```
<form id="rform" name="formsort" action=""  method="post">
<select name="sort" id="sort" onChange="document.forms['formsort'].submit()">
<option value="default">Sort Results</option>
<option value="lowhigh">Price: Low to High</option>
<option value="highlow">Price: High to Low</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i have checked your code again and found that it is clear and the solution is also clear :)

Ad 3 hidden element into the form of sorting each one named by (title,book,author) successively and store the values posted from the search action so when you will sort the results you will also applying these constraints because are posted again :)

I mean you must add the following code after the  inside the sorting form you are using :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['title']))
        {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="title" value="'.$_POST['title'].'" />';
        }
    if(isset($_POST['author']))
        {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="author" value="'.$_POST['author'].'" />';
        }
    if(isset($_POST['isbn']))
        {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="'.$_POST['isbn'].'" />';
        }
    if(isset($_POST['keyword']))
        {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="'.$_POST['keyword'].'" />';
        }
    if(isset($_POST['sort']))
    {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="sort" value="'.$_POST['sort'].'" />';
    }

?>
```

Hope this will help you :) Let me know if any additional help needed :)

Comment: How would I go about hiding it?

Comment: @user2197354 : What you need in your sorting form after closing the select tags is exactly that :

<?php if(isset($_POST['title'])){echo '<input type="hidden" name="title" value="'.$_POST['title'].'" />';}?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['author'])){echo '<input type="hidden" name="author" value="'.$_POST['author'].'" />';}?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['isbn'])){echo '<input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="'.$_POST['isbn'].'" />';}?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){echo '<input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="'.$_POST['keyword'].'" />';}?>

Please let me know if this works :)

Comment: I have no idea how to insert a hidden element into a form, I don't have much experience. Any pointers on where I should start would be great :)

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but it's still sorting all results :(

Comment: If this also doesn't work , please can you post the content of the javascript function that will submit the form :)

I think their were a small error around us we must work hardly to detect it :)

Comment: Should I have a JavaScript function included?

Comment: It is not necessary but i say taht supposing that you are using a javascript function to submit this form

Look i think you must do a var_dump($_POST) in your page that will show results and detect how posted variabled acts

for the first time you access the page what do you have as posted variables

Then after applying some search condition what variables are posted

Then after sorting the result what variable sorted

And in this way we will have ability to stop on the exactly problem that have situation :)

Comment: Thank-you so much for your help, I never would have got that. Much appreciated :)

Comment: For nothing ! And don't hesitate to ask me anything you need and i will try to help you as i can :)

Comment: Thank-you. I'm sorry to keep hassling you. But if you ever get a chance, would you be able to provide any help with the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685757/pass-session-variable-to-new-page-when-link-is-clicked

Comment: Don't worry i have add a comment on it and wish that you clarify your code by preventing putting php inside html and try to echo what you want as html using the php echo instead of writing plan html then your code is really confusing a lot so please i hope that you will explain the idea you are working around and if you can post your exactly code because really i don't know the 2 blocks you have posted how  exists in your code are the both in the same file and which block is before the other ! In general your code posted need more explanation so i can give you my maximum help :)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get php to 'remember' the conducted search

It is not actually PHP but rather general idea of HTTP protocol. So, to solve your problem you have to just follow the standard:

> GET method should be used for searches instead of POST. That's defined by HTTP standard and being the very purpose of GET method. While POST shouldn't be used for search.

So, as long as you are using GET method, your data being preserved automatically.

The only issue could be with pagination links. To add current query string to them `http_build_query()` function have to be used.

You could actually reduce the amount of conditions on your page. Instead of using 2 separate ones

```
if(isset($_GET['title'])){
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
}
if ( ! empty($title))
$where[] = "booktitle LIKE '%" . $title . "%'";
```

one have to be used

```
if(isset($_GET['title'])){
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $where[] = "booktitle LIKE '%" . $title . "%'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at my point of view ,
why are you going for such a drastic sorting ?
you can simply display the result in a table via php, use  `jquery` to sort the table in any way

http://tablesorter.com/docs/
 http://joequery.github.com/Stupid-Table-Plugin/

Answer (score -1):

When you use "ORDER BY" you are sorting the result set, not the database itself. If you would like to grab a fresh copy of the results just do so without the ORDER BY.

Also, PHP's ternary if structure is much better suited here. Instead of :

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])){
   $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
}
```

You can say:

```
$title = (isset($_POST['title']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']) : "");
```

Comment: Thank-you for the tip :) How do I grab a fresh copy of the results though without passing through the first page and inputing the search again?